# write to a C file

Tags: c++, vector

I wrote this C++ code that allows us to create a C file and fill it with a C++ vector like so:

```
std::vector<float> vec{ 1.3, 2.7, 6.9, 4.6 };

bool convertData(std::vector<float> vec, std::string filename="attrib.c")
        {
            std::ofstream f;
            f.open(filename);
            if (!f.is_open())
                return -1;
            f << "float vec[" << vec.size() << "] = {" << vec.data() << "};";
            f.close();
        }
```

but when I opened the .c file I found something like that:

```
float vec[4] = {012051F0};
```

How to correct that?

Comment: You'll probably want to `auto sep = " "; for (auto&& f : vec) { out << sep << f; sep = ", "; }` rather than output of the pointer `vec.data()`.

Comment: why did you expect `<< vec.data()` to write all the data? check what `data` returns

Comment: I also noticed that even though your function returns `bool`, the only thing your function is set to return is `-1` -- which would be converted to a `true` value, since it's nonzero!

Answer (score 2):

You have to loop over the vector and write each value individually. `data()` just gives you the pointer tot the first value.

```
f << "float vec[" << vec.size() << "] = {";

std::string sep;     
for (float v : vec)
{
    f << sep << v;
    sep = " ,";
}

f << "};";
```

Comment: thanks, is what I'm doing correct? because I have to write so many vectors into C file

Comment: What do you mean by `correct`? If you need to create `c` compilable files out of some data, then yes. The actual question is, where you got that vector from and why you need it as a C file.

Comment: I got that actual vector from a C++ file and then I have to generate a C file because I have to work with C files

Comment: But that C++ file, where does it get the values from? Is it some kind of algorith, producing it, or do your read the from a file, in which case, you can read it directly in the C file. It's not clear to me, why you create those C file in the first place.

Comment: because I'm working with a C++ library that contains classes and structs, so I create my own class to get the data from that library and then store them into some vectors and now I want to use those data with C because the platform I'm using I can't use C++

Comment: Isn't the `std::to_string` redundant? `operator<<` can print a floating-point number to a stream just fine.

Comment: @jjramsey, you are right. I had some other implementastion in mind and forgot to remove. Updated.

Comment: @Gigo, I thought as much, as I was doing something similar myself. :)

Comment: Same way, as I showed you above. :) It was to generate data for a program in an emulator.

Answer (score 1):

`vec.data()` is a **pointer** to the `std::vector`'s internal buffer. When you streamed it into the `std::ofstream`, the address got printed. If you want to print your data, you would have to iterate over all of your elements.

Of course, this would be re-inventing the wheel. There are existing libraries for serializing `std::vector`'s and other types to output streams.

Comment: what are the libraries that allow us to do that?

Comment: @Gigo: That depends on your format of interest. For example, if you want a JSON format, you could try [this JSON library](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) (it's one of several). There's also [Boost's Serialization library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).

Comment: I don't have enough knowleadge but I think that this is useful for JSON format, I have vectors. how can I implement it?

Comment: Since you want the data in the `vector` embedded into the array initializer in the output C file, JSON, not the right call. In this case I'd have a loop that iterates through the `vector` and writes out the numbers in the `vector` separated by commas. The hard part will be not printing the comma after the last number in the `vector`.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it just by using **iteration**.

```
std::vector<float> vec{ 1.3, 2.7, 6.9, 4.6 };

bool convertData(std::vector<float> vec, std::string filename = "attrib.c")
{
    std::ofstream f;
    f.open(filename);
    if (!f.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Unable to open file: " << filename << " !";
        return false;
    }
    else {
        f << "float vec[] = {";
        int count = 0;
        for (auto it : vec) { // Iteration with "auto" in vector
            count += 1;
            if (count == vec.size()) { // In order to fix the last comma (,)
                f << " " << it << " "; //Write spaces in front and behind last element
            }
            else {
                f << " " << it << ","; //Write vector data with comma and space
            }
            
        }
        f << "};";
        std::cout << "Done!" << std::endl;
        f.close();
        return true;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::cout << convertData(vec, "attrib.c");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Side note: There is no need for the `" << vec.size() << "` in `"float vec[" << vec.size() << "] = {"` A C compiler will infer the size from the number of elements in the initializer if you leave the square braces empty. ``"float vec[] = {"`` should be all you need.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks i saw it right now! How about adding a counter, pls check out.

Comment: Eljay has a very elegant solution in the second comment under the question.

Comment: @user4581301 Yeah, i saw it right now, it's good and clean. Thanks once more for correcting my mistakes, it really helps me!

Comment: All of the `convertData()` function's `return` statements return values that will be converted to `true` values, since the function returns `bool`. Note that *both* `bool(1)` and `bool(-1)` are `true`. Only `bool(0)` is false. You should probably replace `return -1` with `return false` and `return 1` with `return true`.